# Get clicked version details in the Experience editor through programming in Sitecore SXA?

Tags: experience-editor, versions

I want to fetch clicked version details in the Experience editor through programming. I tried override the `OnLoad` method of the `GalleryVersionsForm` class from the namespace `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Galleries.Versions` in the assembly `Sitecore.Client.dll`. However, it is working fine for the Content editor, not for the Experience editor.

Kindly have a look at the experience editor from where i am selecting version-:

[image]

Comment: maybe for EE mode the ribbon context item is diff ,

Answer (score 4):

It's completely different in `Experience Editor`.

When you click on any of the versions, there is a request to

```
/-/speak/v1/ExperienceEditor/SelectVersion.js
```

It builds an url for selected version, checks if the item has presentation details and finally it calls code similar to:

```
  var url = ExperienceEditor.Web.setQueryStringValue(ExperienceEditor.getPageEditingWindow().location.href, "sc_version", version);
  url = ExperienceEditor.Web.setQueryStringValue(url, "sc_itemid", context.currentContext.itemId);
  ExperienceEditor.navigateToUrl(url);
```

Everything happens in javascript. There is no way of hooking your c# code here.